# How to refresh a fragment

Tags: android, refresh, fragment

I have an Activity that contains a fragment. Is there a simple way to refresh the fragment?
I thought about something like `getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().refresh().commit();`...
But theres nothing like refresh. Any suggestions? My Fragment holds a toast that shows a random number. i want to refreh the fragment so the toast shows a new random number respectively redoes the code from Fragment.onCreateView()

```
public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {

    TextView tv_question;
    Button btn_answer_1;
    Button btn_answer_2;
    Button btn_answer_3;

    public PlaceholderFragment() {
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, 
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_activity_quiz, container, false);

        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), String.valueOf(Math.random()), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        tv_question = (TextView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.tv_question);
        SupportFunctions.setViewBackgroundWithDrawable(tv_question, getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.quiz_question_background));

        btn_answer_1 = (Button)rootView.findViewById(R.id.btn_answer_1);
        btn_answer_2 = (Button)rootView.findViewById(R.id.btn_answer_2);
        btn_answer_3 = (Button)rootView.findViewById(R.id.btn_answer_3);
        SupportFunctions.setViewBackgroundWithDrawable(btn_answer_1, getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.quiz_answer_background));
        SupportFunctions.setViewBackgroundWithDrawable(btn_answer_2, getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.quiz_answer_background));
        SupportFunctions.setViewBackgroundWithDrawable(btn_answer_3, getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.quiz_answer_background));
        btn_answer_1.setOnClickListener(btn_answer_listener);
        btn_answer_2.setOnClickListener(btn_answer_listener);
        btn_answer_3.setOnClickListener(btn_answer_listener);

        // LOAD QUESTION FROM DB

        Globals.setCORRECT_ANSWER(1);

        // SHUFFLE ANSWERS

        return rootView;
    }

    public OnClickListener btn_answer_listener = new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            int id = v.getId();

            if (id == R.id.btn_answer_1 && Globals.getCORRECT_ANSWER() == 1) {
                // correct
                answerCorrect();
            }
            else if (id == R.id.btn_answer_2 && Globals.getCORRECT_ANSWER() == 2) {
                // correct
                answerCorrect();
            }
            else if (id == R.id.btn_answer_3 && Globals.getCORRECT_ANSWER() == 3) {
                // correct
                answerCorrect();
            }
            else {
                answerWrong();
            }

        }

    };

    private void answerCorrect() {

        Globals.incrementAnswersTotal(); // got to become sharedPreference
        Globals.incrementAnswersRound(); 
        Globals.incrementCorrectAnswersTotal(); // sharedPreference
        Globals.incrementCorrectAnswersRound();

        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
        builder.setIcon(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.quiz_ic_dialog_correct));
        builder.setTitle(getResources().getString(R.string.ad_correct_answer_heading));
        builder.setMessage(getResources().getString(R.string.ad_correct_answer_text));
        builder.setPositiveButton(R.string.ad_keep_on, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.container, getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.container)).commit();
            }

        });
        builder.setNegativeButton(R.string.ad_to_menu, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                startActivity(new Intent(getActivity(), ActivityAppLaunch.class));
            }

        });
        builder.setCancelable(false);


        AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
        alert.show();

    }

    private void answerWrong() {

        Globals.incrementAnswersTotal(); // got to become sharedPreference
        Globals.incrementAnswersRound(); 

        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
        builder.setIcon(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.quiz_ic_dialog_wrong));
        builder.setTitle(getResources().getString(R.string.ad_wrong_answer_heading));
        builder.setMessage(getResources().getString(R.string.ad_wrong_answer_text) + "mein Text hier");
        builder.setPositiveButton(R.string.ad_keep_on, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

        });
        builder.setNegativeButton(R.string.ad_to_menu, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                startActivity(new Intent(getActivity(), ActivityAppLaunch.class));
            }

        });
        builder.setCancelable(false);

        AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
        alert.show();

    }

}
```

Comment: What do you mean by `refresh` and what is your use case? Include code.

Comment: load it again. my fragment provides a random number and i want to refresh it, so theres a new random number displayed. see the code above. i need it in my `positiveButton`

Comment: I don't see any random number and no positiveButton. Where is the correct piece of code? Why don't you just generate a new random number? new Random().nextInt();

Comment: i edited it. i basically want to execute the code from onCreateView again

Comment: rather than forcing `onCreateView`, it would be more pragmatic to call a public method on the fragment which could update your view with the random number

Comment: and how can I do this?

Comment: any idea? sorry I'm stuck with this for ages

Answer (score 0):

As Ben Pearson said, instead of putting all your code in onCreateView(), make another method:

```
public void showNewRandomNumber() {
    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), String.valueOf(Math.random()), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

Then call it from wherever you want. It sounds like you want to call it in the onClick method of the positiveButton, so that's where it would go (and if so, then showNewRandomNumber doesn't have to have public visibility).

Comment: but I need everything thats in my onCrearteView() method and how do I get the findViewById() in that function then?

Comment: You can stash the root view in a field.

Comment: ... but you already store the view references in fields, so why do you need to call findViewById again?